# Meu projeto Laravel não sobe no servidor

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3

Estou seguindo o seguinte curso online no site do youtube:

[1 - CRUD en LARAVEL & VUEjs - Webpack, Laravel Mix, NPM, Axios | Rimorsoft Online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5EKLN_1mNW8&t=1s)

Quando vou subir o servidor com o comando `yarn run dev` ele dá uma mensagem de sucesso como você podem ver abaixo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando vou digitar a URL: `http://localhost/laravel-vue-crud/public`
Não aparece nada no Browser

Eu acho que está faltando uma besteira saber o que houve de errado.

Alguém poderia baixar meu projeto do repositório e tentar fazer um teste?

[laravel-crud](https://github.com/wladimirbandeira/laravel-crud/tree/master/laravel-vue-crud)

Eu só estou pendindo essa ajuda porque ele não gerou nenhum erro no **PowerShell**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Artisan** de acordo com a documentação do *Laravel*, é o nome dado a interface da linha de comando incluída com o *Laravel*

Com ele você pode fazer varias operações referentes ao *Laravel*.

Para você ver a lista de comandos disponíveis do *Artisan*, digite o comando abaixo no *Terminal*, *Prompt de Comando*, *PowerShell*.

```
php artisan list
```

Para rodar um servidor local para servir sua aplicação, execute o comando:

```
php artisan serve
```

Exemplo, o comando abaixo ele cria para você uma chave nova randomicamente para sua aplicação, para usar em *Sessões*, *Criptografia*, etc.

```
php artisan key:generate
```

O comando *make* facilita muito na criação de *Controllers*, *Models*, etc, você informa apenas o nome e ele cria o arquivo para você, exemplo:

```
php artisan make:controller Contato // Cria um Controller com o nome Contato
php artisan make:model Contato // Cria um Model com o nome Contato
```

Também é possível trabalhar com entradas *Cron* diretamente pela aplicação *Laravel* sem a necessidade de realizar conexão *SSH*.

E assim por diante, tem vários comandos, se for listar aqui vai levar horas.

### Referência

- [Documentação em Português](http://laravel-docs-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/artisan/)